# XC32 G++ version

Tags: gcc, g++, microchip

The user manual of the XC32 compiler states

> The compiler is a port of the GCC compiler from the Free Software
>   Foundation.

Which is great! Since now I can use GCC/G++ features.

But, I cannot seem to find what version it was ported of (to check if my favorite feature is supported)

I have the lastest XC32 compiler, v1.44.

Can anybody help me find where the GCC/G++ port version is mentioned?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call "xc32-gcc --version" to see this.